# Testing Struts 2 actions, result type freemarker

Tags: spring, junit, struts2, locale, freemarker

I'm trying to test Struts 2 actions which results point to a freemarker page (.ftl). My tests extends StrutsSpringTestCase as I'm using the Spring framework. My problem is that after the action executes it searches for the result freemarker page, but before it gets the page it appends the locale (in my case en_GB) to the ftl page. Thus finding nothing.

For Example :

Action executes - Result Page = login.ftl but searches for login_en_GB.ftl

Action executes - Result Page = index.ftl but searches for index_en_GB.ftl

I can't figure out why it is doing that or how to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround I used for this issue was to stop the process just after executing the action. By doing so I was not taking advantage of the full functionality, but since apparently freemarker was not supported, this was the best way that came to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is to set a mock servlet request on the controller. We do something similar in our code but to mock post requests:

```
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletResponse;

protected HttpServletRequest httpServletPostRequest = new MockHttpServletRequest("POST", "/");
httpServletPostRequest.addPreferredLocale(yourLocale);
controller.setServletRequest(httpServletPostRequest);
```